# CSS position relative forcing the height of element

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I have two (almost) clone elements (`#container` and `#container-shadow`). The same css rules are supposed to be applied equally to them. However, the second `.box3` div element is four times the height it should be. Why is that?

`codepen ->` http://codepen.io/thiagoh/pen/aJwbOZ

CSS code

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  top: -90px;
  left: 400px;
  float: left;
}

#container-shadow div,
#container div {
  width: 280px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box4 {
  background-color: darkgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  left: 10px;
}

.box4 ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box4 li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

HTML code

```
<div style="height: 100px;"></div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="box3">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    <ul>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
      <li>line 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container-shadow">
  <div class="box3">
    why this element is this height?
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    <ul>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
      <li>line 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**current result**

[image]

**expected result**

[image]

PS: Note the position of the boxes. That's the required position in my situation. `clear:both` on `#container-shadow` does not fix my problem.

Comment: Can you post an image of what exactly the layout it should be?

Comment: @Pangloss sure!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the float:left on the #container, it should look like this:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  top: -90px;
  left: 400px;
}
```

here is an updated codepen:[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpgaPr)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a `float: left` on your `#container` which is not *cleared* - add this after the `#container`:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

to *clear* the `float` - see demo below:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  top: -90px;
  left: 400px;
  float: left;
}

#container-shadow div,
#container div {
  width: 280px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box4 {
  background-color: darkgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  left: 10px;
}

.box4 ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box4 li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px;"></div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="box3">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    <ul>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
      <li>line 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div><!-- ADDED THIS -->

<div id="container-shadow">
  <div class="box3">
    why this element is this height?
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    <ul>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
      <li>line 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

If you don't want the `#container-shadow` to drop down, you can *relatively* position it and *float* it to *left* using something like this:

```
#container-shadow {
  float: left;
  left: -275px;
  position: relative;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  top: -90px;
  left: 400px;
  float: left;
}

#container-shadow div,
#container div {
  width: 280px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box4 {
  background-color: darkgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  left: 10px;
}

.box4 ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box4 li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

#container-shadow {
  float: left;
  left: -275px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px;"></div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="box3">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    <ul>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
      <li>line 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container-shadow">
  <div class="box3">
    why this element is this height?
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    <ul>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
      <li>line 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would suggest removing `float` and use `inline-block` for `#container` and `#container-shadow` (note that I have swapped their position in the markup) and then apply *positioning* to the `#container` to get the desired result:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  top: -90px;
  left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#container-shadow {
  display: inline-block;
}

#container-shadow div,
#container div {
  width: 280px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box4 {
  background-color: darkgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  left: 10px;
}

.box4 ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box4 li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px;"></div>

<div id="container-shadow">
  <div class="box3">
    why this element is this height?
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    <ul>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
      <li>line 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="box3">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    <ul>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
      <li>line 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for this answer, but using `clear:both` the div is thrown down the page and that's not the result I'm expecting. I expect the `#container-shadow` remains in the position it is but with the correct height. did I explained myself?

Comment: @thiagoh check out the edited answer and let me know, thanks!

Comment: thank you again. Yeah, I had already done this changes to my code, but the `left: -Xpx` sounded as bad code.. is there any other elegant way?

Comment: I guess you should use `inline-block` for `container` and `container-shadow` instead of using `float` and `relative` positioning...

Answer (score 0):

An element with `position: relative;` is positioned relative to its normal position.

Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. **Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element**.

The `float: left` attempts to force container-shadow to occupy this space causing distortion.

It's your same code just comment the float:

```
#container {
      position: relative;
      top: -90px;
      left: 400px;
      /* float: left;*/
}

#container-shadow div,
#container div {
  width: 280px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box4 {
  background-color: darkgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  left: 10px;
}

.box4 ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box4 li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple.

Remove this:

```
float: left;
```